# PHP Grab $_POST values without knowing values beforehand

Tags: php, mysql, http-post

A friend told my you can grab stuff from a general $_POST array, but I'm not getting it.

What I have are some values with unique row IDs pulled from a MySQL DB. I have them displayed so they can be updated if necessary en masse. I've given each input form a unique name by concat'ing the MySQL value, but I'm unsure how to grab those values in the script that accepts the $_POST values.

```
<form action"./" method="POST">
<?php
while($select_row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
{
echo $select_row['name'];
echo "</br>";
echo "Week ".$select_row['week'];
echo "</br>";
echo "Hours: ";
?>
<input class="options" type="text" name="hours<?php echo $select_row['submission_id']?>" value="<?php echo $select_row['hours']; ?>" />
<?php
echo "</br></br>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Hours">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

As you can see, each input will get a name like hours13 or hours144. Without knowing what they will be named beforehand, how can I extract them from $_POST?

Comment: `name="hours[<?php echo $select_row['submission_id']?]>` then you have a nifty hours array

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Thanks! I've been meaning to, but I'm working on a deadline, and I have to implement things how I know how :( That tutorial looks top notch though, I'll give it a go when I'm done with this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through the collection:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value != '')
    {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to also institute and if statement using $key=>value? Like if $key=>value != NULL or some such?

Comment: Sure. I'll update the post. The $Key won't be there unless it's set and the $value will be set if the $key is there, so we simply check if the $value is empty.